# Unable to set date to the ng Bootstrap datepicker in Angular

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular8, ng-bootstrap

I am working in Angular where I am using ng Bootstrap Datepicker in a Reactive form

I tried to set value to the ngBootstrap DatePicker with Patch Value But Unable to set value to it

I am sharing my code

Html

```
<div class="form-group required control-label">
  <label>Date of Joining</label>
  <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="doj"  placeholder=""/> -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control"  formControlName="doj" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" ngbDatepicker
                #e="ngbDatepicker">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="e.toggle()" type="button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
this.employeeForm.patchValue({
  doj: this.date
})
```

Comment: ngbDatePicker are "feed" (by defect) by an object with year,month and day, so you can do, e.g. `this.employeeForm.patchValue({doj:{year:2020,month:92;day:06}})` -or `this.date={year:2020,month:92;day:06};this.employeeForm.patchValue({doj:this.date})`. You can also use an Adapter to use Javascripts Date object, see https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#date-model

Answer (score 0):

ngbDatepicker uses NgbDateStruct interface as a model and not the native Date object.

```
this.employeeForm.patchValue({
doj : { year: 2020, month: 2, day: 6 } // should be { year , month , date } format
})
```

or create custom parser formatter.

```
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { isNumber, toInteger, padNumber } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/util/util';

@Injectable()
export class NgbDateCustomParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {
  parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
    if (value) {
      const dateParts = value.trim().split('-');
      if (dateParts.length === 1 && isNumber(dateParts[0])) {
        return {day: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: null, year: null};
      } else if (dateParts.length === 2 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1])) {
        return {day: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: toInteger(dateParts[1]), year: null};
      } else if (dateParts.length === 3 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1]) && isNumber(dateParts[2])) {
        return {day: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: toInteger(dateParts[1]), year: toInteger(dateParts[2])};
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
    return date ?
        `${isNumber(date.day) ? padNumber(date.day) : ''}-${isNumber(date.month) ? padNumber(date.month) : ''}-${date.year}` :
        '';
  }
}
```

Set the provider for the custom parser formatter in the @NgModule.

```
providers: [
    {provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDateCustomParserFormatter}
   ]
```